# Difference between two statements with switched multiple quantifiers

Tags: proof-writing, quantifiers

Does that slight change between Exercises 1 and 2 make a difference to their solutions ? Is it wrong to use recycle Exercise 1's solution for Exercise 2?

**Exercise 1:**
Prove or disprove that $$\forall a{\in}\mathbb Z\; \forall b{\in}\mathbb Z\; \exists c{\in}\mathbb Z\; a|(b+c).\tag1$$
**Exercise 2:**
Prove or disprove that $$\forall a{\in}\mathbb Z\; \exists c{\in}\mathbb Z\;  \forall b{\in}\mathbb Z\; a|(b+c).\tag2$$

**My solution to Exercise 1:**

Let $a_0$ be a fixed, but arbitrary integer.

Let $b_0$ be a fixed, but arbitrary integer.

Choose $c_0 \in \mathbb Z.$

I must prove that $a$ divides $b+c$. I must prove that $\exists k \in \mathbb Z$ such that $a = k(b+c).$

$a = kb+kc.$

$c = \frac{a-kb}{k}.$

Choose $c = \frac{a-kb}{k}$. I have shown that $\forall a \in \mathbb Z, \forall b \in \mathbb Z, \exists c \in \mathbb Z$ such that $a$ divides $b+c.$

Comment: You chose $c$ in terms of $a$ and $b$. You cannot use this $c$ before $b$ is even mentioned. Try to disprove the second claim.

Comment: So, I am not allowed to make choices on fixed variables based on arbitrary variables that haven't yet been 'declared', is that correct ?

Comment: Exactly, this is it.

Comment: Statement 2 logically implies statement 1 (but not vice versa).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be useful to try to read it out in English.    "Given any number $a$ and a second number $b$,  does there exist (AKA can I always find at least one) third number $c$ such that $a|(b+c)$.

Before trying to prove it if it doesn't seem obvious, try it with  some examples.  For example,  what about $a=5$, $b=2$?  Can you find a $c$ such that $5|(2+c)$?

There are in fact an infinite number of examples, but there are two that are simplest:  Every number divides itself and every number divides 0.   Can you generalize either of these to find a $c$ such that either $a=b+c$ or $0=b+c$?

The second claim asks, given a generic number $a$, does there exist a single number $c$ such that for EVERY possible number $b$,  $a|(b+c)$.

Again, try an example.  Say $a=5$.   Now,  can you think of number $c$ such that for every $b$,  $5|(b+c)$?  Hint:  If $5|n$ then $5\not| (n+1)$